# Minimizing the sum of an array as exponent to the base 2

Tags: or-tools, minizinc

I have a problem that roughly does the following

```
set of int: SIZE = 1..3;
array[SIZE] of int: bound;
array[SIZE] of var int: cost;

constraint forall(i in SIZE) (cost[i] > bound[i]);

solve minimize sum(i in SIZE) (2^cost[i]);
```

I guess due to the way CP solver works, this is not possible. Or-tools throws the error

> evaluation error: comprehension iterates over an infinite set

At the moment I opted for a hacky way to at least minimize the biggest exponent and how many times it occures with

`solve minimize max(cost)*100+count(cost, max(cost));`

Is there a nice and efficient way to take the elements of an array as exponent to the base 2, sum it and minimize the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you model stems from the fact that OR-Tools (and Gecode) do not have propagators for `pow` with variable exponents. They will instead rewrite the expression to work on each possible value that the exponent can take, and then choose the result based on the chosen value.

However, when your expression is `var int` the set of possible value is infinite, and this is not possible. This is why MiniZinc will complain and throw an error. The fix is simply to provide both upper and lower bounds on your `cost` variables. For example, we could say that they have to be between 0 and 10, and the model will function as expected.

```
set of int: SIZE = 1..3;
array[SIZE] of int: bound;
array[SIZE] of var 0..10: cost;

constraint forall(i in SIZE) (cost[i] > bound[i]);

solve minimize sum(i in SIZE) (2^cost[i]);
```

(Alex' solution also is correct, but does some of the rewriting manually even though this is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The following MiniZinc model compiles and finds a solution.
*OR Tools* or *Gecode* are used as solver backends.

```
set of int: SIZE = 1..3;
set of int: DOMAIN = 0..20;
array[SIZE] of int: bound;
array[SIZE] of var DOMAIN: cost;

%  tcost[i] = 2 ** cost[i]
array[SIZE] of var int: tcost;

constraint forall(i in SIZE) (cost[i] > bound[i]);

%  https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-flatzinc-int.html#mzn-flatzinc-int-int-pow
constraint forall(i in SIZE) (int_pow(2, cost[i], tcost[i]));

solve minimize sum(i in SIZE) (tcost[i]);
```

The value range for `cost` is now limited to `DOMAIN` to avoid overflows.
Built-in predicate [int_pow](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-flatzinc-int.html#mzn-flatzinc-int-int-pow) is used to calculate integer exponentiation. This assumes positive exponents.

Rather than using [int_pow](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.6.4/en/lib-flatzinc-int.html#mzn-flatzinc-int-int-pow), you could use a suitably sized int array and enforce that each array entry is the double of its predecessor.